# Is NULL a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, null, conceptual, concept

So, I had an argument with my professor earlier defending that NULL is not a pointer, but he kept on insisting that it is because there is such a thing as NULL pointer. So, here I am now a little bit confused if NULL is really a pointer or not

I already tried search over the internet but couldn't find any answer, so my last resort is here

Comment: So what do you think when assigning NULL to a pointer? What does it contain?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "is a pointer". Since you tagged this "conceptual", I think you may be using the term "pointer" in a sense different from the formal language definition.

Comment: @phuclv the pointer points to nothing or zero

Comment: a pointer that points to nothing is a null pointer

Comment: @Joe: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Comment: It's an integral constant in C++ and 0 cast to `(void *)` in POSIX.

Answer (score 4):

In C, `NULL` is a macro that expands to a null pointer constant.

[7.19p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19p3)

> The macros are
>
> NULL which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant;
>   ...

A null pointer constant is an integer constant expression with the value `0` (
e.g., `0`, `1-1`, `42*0LL`, etc.) or such an expression cast to `(void*)`.

[6.3.2.3p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p3)

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression
>   cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant.66) If a null
>   pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting
>   pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a
>   pointer to any object or function.

Most common C  implementations define `NULL` to be `0`, `0L`, or `((void*)0)`.

So you *are* correct. `NULL` need not be a pointer.

(IIRC, C++ doesn't even allow the `(void*)` cast in `NULL`, meaning `NULL` in C++ always has integer type. Because of that and because `void*` pointers
do not compare with regular pointers so readily in C++, C++>=11 now has a special `nullptr` keyword.)

Comment: @Joe If it has the `(void *)` cast in it, then it does have (the void) pointer type.

Comment: @Joe `NULL` is a macro expanding to a nonspecific value which can be compared with pointers for equality. The `NULL` value may have the void-pointer type or it may be an integer. Usually it's  `0`, `0L` or `((void*)0)`.

Comment: @PSkocik Note that this question was tagged "conceptual", not "language-lawyer", so my guess is that the question is not so much about `NULL` the macro as it is about "the null pointer" as a concept.

Answer (score 3):

`NULL` itself is not a pointer, it is a macro that can be used to initialize a pointer to the *null pointer* value of its type. When compared to a pointer, it compares equal if the pointer is a *null pointer* and unequal if the pointer is a valid pointer to an object of its type.

There is no semantic difference between `char *p = 0;` and `char *p = NULL;` but the latter is more explicit and using `NULL` instead of `0` is more informative in circumstances where the other operand is not obviously a pointer or if comparing to an integer looks like a type mismatch:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("myfile", "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    /* report the error */
}
```

Similarly, there is no semantical difference in C between `'\0'` and `0`, they both are `int` constants. The first is the null byte, the second the null value. Using `0`, `'\0'` and `NULL` wisely may seem futile but makes code more readable by other programmers and oneself too.

The confusion may come from misspelling or mishearing the *null pointer* as *the `NULL` pointer*. The C Standard was carefully proof read to only use *null pointer* and refer to `NULL` only as the macro `NULL`.

Note however that one the accepted definitions of `NULL`, `#define NULL ((void*)0)` makes `NULL` a *null pointer* to `void`.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing about the idea of a 'pointer to address 0' that's a problem.

The rule is that you're disallowed from derefencing it... it's allowed to exist, and if created will meet any criteria for "pointerhood" I can think of.
Just because it's not meaningfully a pointer *to* something...